# Замена только текста в HTML коде

Tags: javascript, jquery

К примеру, есть HTML код:

```
<div class="w1 pa" style="top:0;padding:5px 15px;text-align:center;">
<a id="connect" href="#" class="action yes et2">Получить список доменов</a>
<a id="delete_all" href="#" class="action no et2 f_r">Удалить все</a>
<a id="count_all" href="#" class="action save et2">Посчитать все письма</a>
<a id="filter" href="#" class="action save et2">Фильтровать</a>
</div>
```

Во-первых, текст внутри кода может быть любой: русский, английский, знаки, цифры и т.п.
Во-вторых, данный HTML код будет в переменной JS.

Значит, мне нужно заменить все буквы в данном HTML коде на то, что я сам захочу. К примеру, все буквы `А` заменить на `<span>1</span>`, и так далее...

Важно! Код HTML может быть другой, а не статический. Нужен скрипт, который будет искать в коде буквы, заменять выбранную мною букву на совершенно другое.

Comment: _все буквы "а", и большую и маленькую, заменить на хтмл код "a"_ с этого момента подробнее, пожалуйста. Вы хотите иметь возможность, не трогая уже существующие теги, добавлять новые?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так ведь можно и JavaScript изучить, пока ваши задачки порешаешь)) JS only.

```js
var Str = '<div class="w1 pa" style="top:0;padding:5px 15px;text-align:center;">\
<a id="connect" href="#" class="action yes et2">Получить список доменов</a>\
<a id="delete_all" href="#" class="action no et2 f_r">Удалить все</a>\
<a id="count_all" href="#" class="action save et2">Посчитать все письма</a>\
<a id="filter" href="#" class="action save et2">Фильтровать</a>\
</div>';

function fAccurateReplace(sSourceStr, rExp, sSubstr) {
  
  var oFakeElement = document.createElement('PRE');
  oFakeElement.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', sSourceStr);
  
  var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(oFakeElement, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, false);
  while (treeWalker.nextNode()) {
    treeWalker.currentNode.parentElement.innerText = treeWalker.currentNode.parentElement.textContent.replace(rExp, sSubstr);
  }
  return oFakeElement.innerHTML
}

console.log(fAccurateReplace(Str, /(о.*?т)/gi, '(ЗАМЕНА)'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Хотелось бы услышать что именно с каждой буквой должно быть и зачем.
Так же, ни чего нет про входные данные.

Например, в моём решении, пусть входные данные это массив определённых строк

```js
const str = `<div class="w1 pa" style="top:0;padding:5px 15px;text-align:center;">
<a id="connect" href="#" class="action yes et2">Получить список доменов</a>
<a id="delete_all" href="#" class="action no et2 f_r">Удалить все</a>
<a id="count_all" href="#" class="action save et2">Посчитать все письма</a>
<a id="filter" href="#" class="action save et2">Фильтровать</a>
</div>`;
var data = [
 'Список доменов получен',
 'Всё давно удалено',
 'Письма подсчитаны',
 'Отфильтрованы'
];
function replaceMath(data) {
 let $newStr = $(str).clone(),
  i = 0;
 $("> *", $newStr).each(function(){
  $(this).text(data[i]);
  ++i;
 });
 return $newStr.prop('outerHTML');
}

var newStr = replaceMath(data);
console.log(newStr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Но, скорее всего, ни это нужно топикстартеру. Расписывайте всё подробно, а не в куче, как в ваших последних трёх предложениях.

Answer (score 0):

С помощью jquery - `$('#el_id').text('Some English ');`

Comment: данный HTML код будет в переменной js© эт строка. почему-то они все так и мечтают работать со строками. регулярок не писали